# android send facebook message from my application

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, openid, android-account

I want to send facebook message (private message) or share a new post from my application using the facebook account logged in from Facebook application or ask the user to log in if there is no Facebook application installed,

I have read that facebook's API (Graph API) that helps to do so is now deprecated, 
is there a workaround? another solution? can i use (Graph API) even it is deprecated (will facebook disable it)?

thank you in advance

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android#message

Comment: thank you, checking those links. what about sending the message in the background so the user haven't to click something, of course he must grant the application the permission to do so .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that Facebook no longer supports this feature on the new Graph API version,

i implemented a solution using native Http requests.